# Asyncio, Autobahn, Websocket. Многопоточность Python

Tags: python, websocket, асинхронность, asyncio

Кто нибудь использовал Autobahn / Asyncio ?

Код прямо из документации Autobahn (кроме onMessage) :

```
import asyncio, time 
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol) :
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary) :
        print(id(self))
        time.sleep(10)
        print(id(self))

Factory = WebSocketServerFactory('ws://192.168.0.1:10000', debug = False)
Factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
loop   = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro   = loop.create_server(Factory, '192.168.0.1', 10000)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt :
    pass
finally:
    server.close()
    loop.close()
```

Подключаются два клиента. Первый посылает сообщение, через пару секунд посылает второй.

Так вот пока у первого не отработает метод, второй ждет.

Ну и вывод в этом случае :

```
47556048
47556048
48672560
48672560
```

Хотя должен быть :

```
47556048
48672560
47556048
48672560
```

Почему нет асинхронности? Может что-то в коде не так?

Comment: Ни time.sleep, ни сам onMessage асинхронными вообще не являются и ей тут взяться неоткуда. (Хотел написать исправленный пример в ответ, а у меня Autobahn не заработал, придётся ограничиться комментом)

Comment: @andreymal, а мне так нужен исправленный пример).. Если есть что-то по теме в документации, пришлите пожалуйста ссылку. А то я что-то ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для асинхронности, метод onMessage должен быть оформлен соответствующим образом :

http://autobahn.ws/python/websocket/examples.html#slow-square